# Facebook SDK 7.2 Unity ios share link crash

Tags: ios, facebook-unity-sdk, unity-game-engine

I am using facebook SDK 7.2 and Unity 5.2. This crash also happens in example code of facebook

My game is crashing **after** successfully sharing score on facebook ios app. Here is crash error message and the screenshot of crash:

```
-[_WebSafeForwarder removeObject:] unrecognized selector sent to instance 
libc++abi.dylib: terminate_handler unexpectedly threw an exception
```

[image]

This is my sharing code in Unity:

[image]

Comment: As a suggestion, try not to use named parameters.. Use all of the paramenters, and if you don't need them, just put the default value.

Don't know in the latest version, but in the past Facebook SDK worked really bad with named parameters.

Comment: on which iOS version are you testing?

Comment: try upgrading the Facebook Unity SDK to Version 7.2.2. this might have been fixed see here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/change-log